# The independence of the continuum hypohtesis

Tags: logic, set-theory

I just finished a short course on the basics of set theory (axioms, ordinals, cardinals, construction of real numbers, etc) but we did not talk anything about models.

I am interested in particular in the proof of the independence of the continuum hypothesis from ZFC and I have been recommended the book *Set theory* by Kenneth Kunen, the 2013 edition. Problem is this book seem to contain a lot more than what I need, just the background section has over 100 pages. Is there any "path" through the book that leads to this particular proof?

P.D. Any other source is  welcomed too. I just happen to have access to a printed copy of this book so it's easier.

Edit: I found this book *Set theory and the continuum hypothesis* by Cohen, it seems to fit perfectly well with my needs, it even has an introduction to logic as well as set theory and its only 150 pages, any opinions?

Comment: Not an answer to the exact question you ask, but a (probably more accessible) exposition of the proof can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1320)

Comment: Thank you! I will start by reading that.

Comment: I recommend John Bell's _Boolean valued models of set theory_, which is, I think, shorter than Kunen's book and is precisely aimed at introducing forcing (although it does it in a slightly different manner than many introductions to forcing do, that is, it starts with boolean algebras rather than with generic filters on posets).

Comment: You can "read to understand a proof" and you can "read to understand". The problem with the former is that your foundation is likely to be narrow, so building very high is not going to work; the problem with the latter, as you obviously point out is that it requires a lot of work. Understanding the independence of CH requires the first few steps into modern set theory, into inner model theory, and into forcing. All of which rely on complicated and somewhat different approaches to the problem. So working "just towards one proof" is the wrong approach here.

Comment: I agree with that, but I believe it doesn't have to be black or white. In between reading the whole book and taking the minimal path to get to the proof, there has to be something that allows a good grasp on the theory behind it.

Comment: I would suggest the previous set theory book by Kunen. You can skip chapter 2 (on infinitary combinatorics), and chapter 1 should mostly be review. You should also be able to skip most of the material on constructibility, OD and HOD.

Comment: I also have Kunen's 1980 book SetTheory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs. You need  Chapter 2 (Infinitary Combinatorics) Section 2, Parts  2.1 to 2.4 about posets, anti-chains, extensions, etc., and some of the parts of Chapter 4 (Easy Consistency Proofs) about relativization and aboluteness  and models, to understand Chapter 7 (Forcing), sections 1,2,3 to understand section 5, where  $con(ZFZ)\to con(ZFC+\neg CH)$ is shown.

Comment: I agree that it's not as black and white here. But let me ask you this. What is your endgame? Do you want to be a set theorist, or a logician of some sort, or do you just want to be able to say "I once knew the proof of the independence of CH" many years from now?

Comment: I certainly don't plan on becoming a set theorist or logician, although it's a subject I find really interesting. So the goal would be to satisfy my curiosity. For that matter, knowing the general idea wouldn't do, I need things proven properly, but on the other hand I only have so much time to spare this summer. Therefore my search for that optimal tone of grey.

Comment: Reading any book about forcing written pre-70s is a bad idea.

Comment: It is starting to become clear that the long path I am trying to avoid is the shortest. I think I'll start with that and hope to have enough time to reach the end.

Comment: That is procrastination 101. "The longest path to thoroughly complete a task is the shortest path; and so in order to avoid logical paradoxes, one has to try each and every shortcut first in order to make the longest path the shortest in hindsight".

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with Andres Caicedo slightly, based on my own experience learning forcing: I think that the beginning of chapter 2 would be good to read. Learning how to use Martin's axiom will secretly teach you a lot about how forcing works, and in my experience is easier than diving straight into the proof.

Now, showing that CH is independent of ZFC consists of two pieces: showing that it's *consistently true*, and that it's *consistently false*. The only way to do the latter is via forcing. The former, however, has two methods: you can prove it with forcing, or by using $L$ (chapter VI, specifically section 4).

My suggestion is to do forcing for each part - that cuts down on the amount of reading you have to do, and also introduces you to two very different basic forcing arguments, based on two different important combinatorial properties: the countable chain condition, and countable closure.

As to forcing itself, after the first bit of chapter II you'll be ready to leap to chapter VII. Here Kunen's treatment is a bit opaque: I tried to self-study forcing, and wasn't able to (although once I got an intuition for the basic details Kunen was *wonderful* - you just need that first "push" to get started). I think here it might be good to take a break from Kunen and look at another source, perhaps the essay [A beginner's guide to forcing](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1320), which takes a more informal tack; once you know what a forcing notion and a name are supposed to be doing, go back to Kunen, and you should be ready to tackle chapter $7$!

Comment: Learning Martin's axiom to understand the proof of $\lnot\mathsf{CH}$? I do not think this helps much. If you want to learn forcing properly, and applications, then of course, but I always found awkward to justify the reverse engineering (the construction of strange posets with technical properties) present in arguments involving Martin's axiom, without knowing forcing.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo It will of course vary person to person. For myself, it certainly helped a lot, and it gave me a good sense of the power of dense sets and the idea that different posets behave differently. I don't think there's a need to look at any of the truly complicated examples; I think looking at a couple basic cardinal characteristics, and maybe building a Ramsey ultrafilter for kicks, is enough. But without this, the dense sets come out of nowhere, and defining the poset the "right" way seems like magic (at least that was my experience).

Comment: I think it gets to the fact that it's often easier to prove something from additional axioms than to build a model with some properties. The MA experience (which is the name of my [Boston cover band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_(band))) tells us that being able to meet lots of dense sets gives us combinatorial results; this helps motivate forcing as a good thing to try to get models with combinatorial properties.

Comment: Noah, so you have more than a feeling that the additional axioms would help? ;)